# How does facebook android app prevent itself from getting killed

Tags: android, facebook

I have noticed that the facebook android app is extremely resilient and cannot be shut down. Even though I have forced stop the application and killed all its associated services, it is somehow able to magically restart itself after a while.

This leads me to the questions:

1) How do I actually stop the app and all facebook services without uninstalling it.

2) What methodology does the app apply to prevent itself from getting killed (i.e. how do you program something similar in android)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) How do I actually stop the app and all facebook services without
>   uninstalling it.

Process termination is executed whenever Android needs more resources to handle logic of another processes of higher priority. 
How does it apply to the Android's `Service`?

The Service returns specific code in `onStartCommand()`:

[START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) - briefly speaking, once the application's process is killed by returning this constant we ask the OS to restore the application's `Service` whenever available resources appear. Thus, the application's process is recreated.

[START_NOT_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY) - once the application's process is killed by returning this constant we tell the OS to not to bother about our Service recreation.

[START_REDELIVER_INTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) - same as [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) but with subtle distinction. Whenever our `Service` is restored we demand to have the `onStartCommand()` with same `Intent` we delivered for the last time before termination.

The explanation for your observations could be that Facebook uses aforementioned constants to bring Services back to work.

> 2) What methodology does the app apply to prevent itself from getting
>   killed (i.e. how do you program something similar in android)?

Few things are worth remembering whenever we want to prevent our application from being a first candidate to be terminated:

1. Relying on [Activity.onLowMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onLowMemory()) or [Application.onLowMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory()) methods - if we hide the application to the background or abandon it then this method is invoked. In this case it is worth releasing resources including:

   - Caches or Cache entries (e. g. LruCache),
   - Expensive objects (Bitmap, temporary POJOs, etc.)
   - unregistering dynamic BroadcastReceivers
2. [Unregistering statically declared broadcast receivers](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/manifest-receivers.html) whenever we don't need them.
3. [Preventing application from having memory leaks](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) - most of the processes leaking their memory are undisputably the first ones to be terminated by the system.
4. Preventing from objects creation and designing our code to be immutable ([book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)) ([link](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value))
5. organizing our HTTP requests in batches ([link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager)) ([link](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)) ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)) ([link](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)) instead executing them on demand.

Hope that helps somehow.